# Corner case where CSS properties pass through the Shadow DOM even though :host {all: initial}

Tags: javascript, html, css, inheritance, shadow-dom

this is probably my first question on Stack! I found what I believe is a corner case to CSS properties passing through the shadow DOM despite the famous fix proposed [here](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/).

**General Context**
I am building a chrome extension where I inject a popup in the website. And I found that the popup can have different fonts depending on the page where it shows up despite having a Shadow DOM in place for the popup.

**Shadow DOM and inheritable properties**

I learned that inheritable properties tend to pass through the shadow DOM, which kinda makes sense. For example, if you have `{font-weight: bold}`, it will pass to all the elements in your shadow DOM unless you specify a different value for `font-weight` for the elements in your shadow DOM.

The solution I found for that was to set all the elements for the host of the shadow root to their default value. That way, nothing is going to leak. Below is an example of how we're protecting the properties `font-weight` and `color` in our main DOM from leaking to the shadow DOM.

```
<head>
    <style>
        #mainbod {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let wr = document.getElementById('tata-wrapper');
            let shadow = wr.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            wr.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style> :host { all : initial} !important </style>`
            let xp = document.createElement('div')
            xp.id = 'explainAI'
            xp.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                .cbd {
                    background-color: rgb(190, 218, 228);
                }
            </style>

            <div id="popup-container">
                <div class="cbd first">
                    <span>Something else here, maybe this or that.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
            wr.shadowRoot.appendChild(xp)
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainbod">
        <div>
            <p> Some other text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tata-wrapper">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Edge Case**

Great so far! Turns out, this is not robust. If one of the properties in the host (in this case `tata-wrapper`) happened to be set to `inherit`, that value will leak. Here is an example where we set all the properties of `tata-wrapper` to inherit. That `:host { all: initial}` fix no longer works. And we will see that the elements inside the shadow DOM will be **red and bold**.

```
<head>
    <style>
        #mainbod {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }

        #tata-wrapper {
            all: inherit
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            let wr = document.getElementById('tata-wrapper');
            let shadow = wr.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            wr.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style> :host { all : initial} !important </style>`
            let xp = document.createElement('div')
            xp.id = 'explainAI'
            xp.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                .cbd {
                    background-color: rgb(190, 218, 228);
                }
            </style>

            <div id="popup-container">
                <div class="cbd first">
                    <span>Something else here, maybe this or that.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
            wr.shadowRoot.appendChild(xp)
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainbod">
        <div>
            <p> Some other text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tata-wrapper">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Tentative Solution**

The only solution I found for this was to actually set the value of the `all` to `initial` for the actual parent (i.e. `tata-wrapper`. I did it as follows

```
// start of the code ... 
let wr = document.getElementById('tata-wrapper');
wr.style.all = 'initial';
let shadow = wr.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
wr.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<style> :host { all : initial} !important </style>`
let xp = document.createElement('div')
xp.id = 'explainAI'
// rest of the code
```

I figured this is not a great solution and might potentially be dangerous. Wondering if someone has a solution.

Comment: Doesn't ``:host{all:initial}`` have a **lower specificity** than ``#tata-wrapper{all:inherit}``?

Comment: And ``<style> :host { all : initial} !important </style>`` is invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'm not sure if it has a lower specificity, does it? What do you think about my tentative solution? I'm still pretty new to web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter `all:initial` playground to learn from,
see what happens when you *remove* the `!important` (in both settings)

Note how *your* `!important` notation in your code above is not the correct syntax

```html
<style>
  my-component {
    background: red;
    color: blue !important;
  }
</style>

<my-component></my-component>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
          .attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
          .innerHTML = `
            <style>
             :host {
                display: inline-block;
                all: initial !important; /* correct notation for your goal */
                color: green;
              }
              h1 {
                background:gold;
              }
            </style>
            <h1>Hello Web Component World!</h1>`;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, the `!important` syntax was the issue here. Thank you!